# Vectorized SVM gradient

Tags: python, numpy, svm

I was going through the code for SVM loss and derivative, I did understand the loss but I cannot understand how the gradient is being computed in a vectorized manner

```
def svm_loss_vectorized(W, X, y, reg):

loss = 0.0
dW = np.zeros(W.shape) # initialize the gradient as zero
num_train = X.shape[0]

scores = X.dot(W)
yi_scores = scores[np.arange(scores.shape[0]),y] 
margins = np.maximum(0, scores - np.matrix(yi_scores).T + 1)
margins[np.arange(num_train),y] = 0
loss = np.mean(np.sum(margins, axis=1))
loss += 0.5 * reg * np.sum(W * W)
```

Understood up to here, After here I cannot understand why we are summing up row-wise in binary matrix and subtracting by  its sum

```
binary = margins
binary[margins > 0] = 1
row_sum = np.sum(binary, axis=1)
binary[np.arange(num_train), y] = -row_sum.T
dW = np.dot(X.T, binary)

# Average
dW /= num_train

# Regularize
dW += reg*W

return loss, dW
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let us recap the scenario and the loss function first, so we are on the same page:

Given are `P` sample points in `N`-dimensional space in the form of a `PxN` matrix `X`, so the points are the rows of this matrix. Each point in `X` is assigned to one out of `M` categories. These are given as a vector `Y` of length `P` that has integer values between 0 and `M-1`.

The goal is to predict the classes of all points by `M` linear classifiers (one for each category) given in the form of a weight matrix `W` of shape `NxM`, so the classifiers are the columns of `W`. To predict the categories of all samples `X` the scalar products between all points and all weight vectors are formed. This is the same as matrix multiplying `X` and `W` yielding a score matrix `Y0` that is arranged such that its rows are ordered like theh elements of `Y`, each row corresponds to one sample. The predicted category for each sample is simply that with the largest score.

There are no bias terms so I presume there is some kind of symmetry or zero mean assumption.

Now, to find a good set of weights we want a loss function that is small for good predictions and large for bad predictions and that lets us do gradient descent. One of the most straight-forward ways is to just punish for each sample `i` each score that is larger than the score of the correct category for that sample and let the penalty grow linearly with the difference. So if we write `A[i]` for the set of categories `j`  that score more than the correct category `Y0[i, j] > Y0[i, Y[i]]` the loss for sample `i` could be written as

`sum_{j in A[i]} (Y0[i, j] - Y0[i, Y[i]])`

or equivalently if we write `#A[i]` for the number of elements in `A[i]`

`(sum_{j in A[i]} Y0[i, j]) - #A[i] Y0[i, Y[i]]`

The partial derivatives with respect to the score are thus simply

```
                    | -#A[i]      if j == Y[i]
dloss / dY0[i, j] = {      1      if j in A[i]
                    |      0      else
```

which is precisely what the first four lines you say you don't understand compute.

The next line applies the chain rule `dloss/dW = dloss/dY0 dY0/dW`.

It remains to divide by the number of samples to get a per sample loss and to add the derivative of the regulatization term which the regularization being just a componentwise quadratic function is easy.

Comment: I understand the logic, I understood that from the non-vectorized code, Can you explain how the matrix of 1,0 (margin>0) is used, In non-vectorized we actually use the value in [i][j] i.e (not rounding off to the 1 or 0), here                    
  'margin = scores[j] - correct_class_score + 1', but in vectorized we are rounding up to 1 or 0, wouldn't 'binary[margins > 0] = (actual values which are > 0, not 1, else 0) ' make more sense ?

Comment: Not having the non-vectorized code I can only comment on the vectorized. As I tried to explain in the answer, _for the derivative_ using 1 and 0, not the actual values, is the mathemamtically correct thing to do. Because `dY0[i,j]/dY0[k,l]` is 1 if `i=k,j=l`, 0 else.

Comment: Can you take a look here: https://github.com/huyouare/CS231n/blob/master/assignment1/cs231n/classifiers/linear_svm.py

Comment: They are doing the same thing: `if margin > 0:` ...`dW[j, :] += X[:, i].T`. Be sure to note that the actual value of `margin` is not used in the update.You could write that, avoiding the `if` statement, as `dW[j, :] += (margin > 0) * X[:, i].T`. Which is what the vectorized code is based on.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I found it much easier to understand the whole gradient calculation through looking at the analytic derivation of the loss function in more detail. To extend on the given answer, I would like to point to the derivatives of the loss function [image: Loss function]

with respect to the weights as follows:

1. Loss gradient wrt w_yi (correct class)
    [image: correct class]

Hence, we count the cases where w_j is not meeting the margin requirement and sum those cases up. This negative sum is then specified as weight for the position of the correct class w_yi. (we later need to multiply this value with xi, this is what you do in your code in line 5)

2) Loss gradient wrt w_j (incorrect classes)
 [image: incorrect class]

where 1 is the indicator function, 1 if true, else 0.

In other words, "programatically" we need to apply equation (2) to all cases where the margin requirement is not met, and adding the negative sum of all unmet requirements to the true class column (as in (1)).

So what you did in the first 3 lines of your code is to determine the cases where the margin is not met, as well as adding the negative sum of these cases to the correct class column (j). In the 5 line, you do the final step where you multiply the x_i's to the other term - and this completes the gradient calculations as in (1) and (2).

I hope this makes it easier to understand, let me know if anything remains unclear. [source](https://cs231n.github.io/optimization-1/#analytic)